# How to match each row in a dataframe and fill up a matrix using the information?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a dataframe 'df' which consists of 2 columns: Name & ID.
 The values of **df** are: 
 Name     ID 
 A           001 
 B            004 
 C           004 
 D           006 
 E           007 
 
 I have a matrix **Mat** (intialized with 0s) which contains all the names as row and all possible IDs (including the IDs that are not in **df**, such as 002 and 005) as columns. What I want to do is to match each Name with their IDs in **df**, and put 1 in the specific position in **Mat**. 
 The structure of **Mat** is: 
       001  002  003  004  005  006  007 
 A 
 B 
 C 
 D 
 E

This is my first question here. Apologies for any unintentional mistakes.

Comment: @Rasif Ajwad make a reproducible example (use dput). then give the expected output and also show if you have done any programming

Comment: In this context, that's just `table(df)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew there is an easier way but I just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, include a MWE, like what I have below.

You should be able to do that with:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    Name = LETTERS[1:5]
    , ID = formatC(c(1,4,4,6,7), width = 3, flag = "0")
    , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

Mat <- 
  matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 7
         , dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:5]
                           , formatC(1:7, width = 3, flag = "0")))

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  Mat[df$Name[i], df$ID[i]] <- Mat[df$Name[i], df$ID[i]] + 1
}

Mat
```

Note, in particular, the `stringsAsFactors == FALSE`. Without it, you will need to wrap `df$Name` and `df$ID` in `as.character` because otherwise they will be factors and return their index numerically instead of the character label.

I also added 1 to the position instead of just setting it to "1" as it is unclear from your question if it is possible to have duplicates or not. There are likely more elegant ways to do it if there are no duplicates, particularly if there are not duplicate IDs (like the `diag` solution suggested by @alistaire), but those may fail if there are duplicates and you do not have explicit handling for them.

Edit: How did I get all the way through this and not realize that I was recreating `table` until I read @alistaire's editted comment?

Now you *do* want the factors:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    Name = LETTERS[1:5]
    , ID = factor(formatC(c(1,4,4,6,7), width = 3, flag = "0")
                  , levels = formatC(1:7, width = 3, flag = "0") )
  )

table(df)
```